Texture brush strokes disappear when rendering
I'm trying to render my grease pencil animation, but the rendered frames look different from what I see in Blender. The layers where I used texture brushes disappear almost completely, I can see just a light trace of them. Also it seems that the colour are different when I render the animation (slightly more yellow). Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Really hard to say what the issue is. Each person's case is technically different from every other person's case even if she/he is encountering the same problem. If you could recreate or share a sample blend file in your question with https://blend-exchange.com/, we may be able to offer better input.

Hello,thank you for your answer. I think I found out, the problem was the brushes set I was using. I tried other brushes and they were to be clearly seen on the rendered PNGs
